# Abstract class with multiple inheritance error: Can't instantiate abstract class ... with abstract method

Tags: python, abstract-class

I'm trying to get the following to work:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Abc1(ABC):

    def __init__(self, example_variable_1: int) -> None:
        self.example_variable_1 = example_variable_1


class Abc2(ABC):

    def __init__(self, example_variable_2: int) -> None:
        self.example_variable_2 = example_variable_2

    @abstractmethod
    def example_method(self):
        pass


class Abc3(Abc1, Abc2, ABC):

    def __init__(self, example_variable_1: int, example_variable_2: int):
        Abc1(self).__init__(example_variable_1)
        Abc2(self).__init__(example_variable_2)

    @abstractmethod
    def example_method(self):
        pass


class InstantiateMe(Abc3):
    
    def __init__(self, example_variable_1: int, example_variable_2: int):
        super().__init__(example_variable_1, example_variable_2)

    def example_method(self):
        print("example_method ran")


instance = InstantiateMe(1, 2)
```

However, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Abc2 with abstract method example_method`
```

I've read all the questions on SO on this topic and they all seem to be answered by adding in a missing `abstractmethod` or adjusting the MRO. I *think* I've got both of those covered off so am stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `Abc3.__init__`, where you call `Abc1(self)` and `Abc2(self)`. The second of those is what is giving you the error, since creating an instance of `Abc2` is not allowed (and the first won't do what you want, even though it is technically legal, since `Abc1` doesn't have any abstract methods). You probably want to be doing:

```
Abc1.__init__(self, example_variable_1)
Abc2.__init__(self, example_variable_2)
```

Though, really, you should redesign `Abc1` and `Abc2` to better support collaborative multiple inheritance. Generally, you do that by taking `*args` and/or `**kwargs` and calling `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` before or after doing their own setup.

Comment: Thanks a million for this and a lightbulb moment too. I've always thought of instantiation only happening to the class I reference, NOT any of the parent classes it inherits from. I've also always steered clear of `*args` and `**kwargs` up until now - I'll read up some more.

Comment: The `__init__` method is the most difficult method to get right when it comes to multiple inheritance, especially since positional arguments will need to be in what may be an inconvenient order when using `*args`. Using keyword only arguments may be a good design decision, as it lets you put them in whatever order is most logical, regardless of which base class is going to handle them.